# For log-space machines, why do we care about PRGs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

### Assumptions

- I believe RL can be derandomized in polynomial time:

  - We need to store the following state:

    - The position of the head on the input.
    - The state of the TM
  - Both can be stored with O(log n) bits.
  - We use dynamic programming, building a table of poly(n) size encapsulating the state of the TM. Then, we march along the random bits, calculating the probability of each TM state after reading a given bit.

This should give us *exact* acceptance probability in $poly(n)$ time.

### Observation

People care about prgs for log space machines.

### Question:

Why? What can we do with a prg for RL that we can't do with an exact acceptance probability algo for RL ?

What is implied by a O(log n) seed length PRG for RL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You show that RL$\subseteq$P. Better derandomization could show that RL=L.

Comment: Is this an implication of log n seed length PRGS? It seems possible to me that such log n seed length PRGS are computable in P but not in L.

Comment: @user13175: If we had log(n) seed length PRGS in L, then RL=L because we just try all the different seeds and take the majority answer. But I'm not sure about the converse (nonexistence of $\log n$ seeds in L $\implies$ RL $\neq$ L).